# Differential equation and solution involving light passing through a glass.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I been stumped on this question for a few days and can't seem find an elegant solution ($x = 8.66cm$).   I have found $k = 0.0811$.

Any help appreciated.

The intensity *I* of light diminishes as it passes through glass, the reduction in intensity being proportional to the thickness *x* of glass.  The intensity is 15 as it enters a block of glass 5cm thick, and is 10 when it leaves, find the minimum thickness of glass required to reduce the intensity to zero for the same light source.

I have been using the differential equation $\frac{dI}{dx} = -kI.$

Thanks in advance

Postscript:  Thanks to A-Level Student the DE to find the solution is

$\frac{dI}{dx} = -kx.$  This reduces the problem to $I = \frac{x^2}{5} + 15.$  Then setting $I = 0$ gives $x = 8.66cm.$

Comment: What do you mean by "reduction in intensity$

Comment: Yeah.... I don't know what that means also....  I have been scratching my head trying to figure out how to set up the DE so I get the solution x = 8.66cm.  Personally I think the question needs a rewrite.

Comment: Your edit is quite significant; please tell us next time that you make a significant error so that we can adjust our answers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the differential equation that you've been using is wrong; the change in intensity is proportional to the thickness, not the intensity itself.

Answer (score 1):

The equation that you use is incorrect: $$dI=-k\ dx$$
The solution of this is $$I_0-I(x)=kx$$
So first you calculate $k$:
$$k=\frac{I_0-I(5)}{5}=1$$
Then you calculate $x$ for $I(x)=0$
$$I_0-0=kx\\15-0=x\\x=15$$

Comment: Why is the equation incorrect?

Comment: You are right A-Level-Student, the DE IS dI/dx = -kx.  Thanks for your help.  It was easier than I thought!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can reduce it to zero unless you account for the quantum nature of light.   Proportion means it will  scale the intensity down.   But if k and x are greater than zero , then k*x will always be nonzero.  The exception is when you reduce the intensity to less than a photon.  The intensity can be made as close to zero as you want, however.